# PHP variable contains HTML and JavaScript. Injecting it into HTML through JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am trying to add some custom PHP code to a Wordpress custom post type.

In a separate php file I have this:

```
<?php


$BuildForm = '<script src="//app.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script>
            <form id="mktoForm_1111"></form>
            <script>MktoForms2.loadForm("//app.marketo.com", "345-XCL-354", 1111,
                function(form) {
                    for ( var ss = document.styleSheets, i = 0, imax = ss.length; i < imax; i++ ) {
                        if ( ( ss[i].href && ss[i].href.indexOf("marketo.com") !== -1 )
                        || ( (ss[i].ownerNode || ss[i].owningElement).parentNode == form.getFormElem()[0] ) ) {
                        }
                    }
                    form.onSuccess(function(values, followUpUrl){
                    location.href = "#";
                    return false;
                    });
                    form.vals({ "comments":"test"});
                });
            </script>';


?>
```

Then in the custom post type in Wordpress I have this:

```
<div id="TheForm" style="max-width:40%; margin: 0 auto;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById("TheForm").innerHTML = '<?php echo $BuildForm; ?>' ;
</script>
```

The problem I am having is that the contents of #TheForm appear as `';`

I am not quite sure what the problem is. Do I need to be formatting the JavaScript that's in the PHP variable in a different way ?

I tried escaping `"` and `/` for example but that didn't help either.

(And before you ask, yes I am including the external php file in my Wordpress custom post type).

Comment: Aye carumba.  Do not inject javascript this way.  Bad, bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's not working! The PHP is executed on the server (which outputs nothing), then rendered by the client, and *then* your javascript runs. Your client-side javascript has no idea what do with PHP.

Your PHP should be returning the fully-formed HTML, like so:

```
<?

$BuildForm = '....';

?>

<div id="TheForm" style="max-width:40%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <?= $BuildForm ?>
</div>
```

Alternatively, change your client-side javascript to fetch your `$BuildForm` HTML via ajax. But it's probably easier to just have your PHP produce the HTML you want.

Answer (score 0):

As your `$BuildForm` variable contains `</script>`, there'll be a `SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF`. Example of the assigned code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <script src="//app.marketo.com/js/forms2/js/forms2.min.js"></script> <!-- </script> tag will be closed here -->
</script>
```

`<script type="text/javascript">` will be closed at `... forms2.min.js"></script>`, which is closed too early.

Thus, the **best alternative way** is to `echo` the form directly into the `div`.

```
<div id="TheForm" style="max-width:40%; margin: 0 auto;"><?php echo $BuildForm; ?></div>
```

Comment: My issue is that I need to be able to allow the Wordpress editors to be able to move this div around. The idea is that they add the div container where they want it, and the javascript gets injected into it.

If I add the div to the php variable then my editors cannot move it around using visual composer in Wordpress.

Comment: Add the JavaScript via admin_enqueue_scripts, not through html injection